# Dagger2 with Androidx, SupportFragmentInjector issue

Tags: android, android-support-library, dagger, androidx

I am trying to implement Dagger2 injection in a new app and the only thing that fails is DaggerAppCompatActivity and SupportFragmentInjector.

When I go to DaggerAppCompatActivity code I see that:

[image]

It tries to reference AppCompatActivity and Fragment from library version before androidx refactor. When I inherit this class I cannot even call setContentView(), beacuse it's unavailable.

I wanted to copy-paste this code into my own base activity, but HasSupportFragmentInjector uses pre-adroidX Fragment.

Is there a way to make it work with AndroidX?

EDIT: this is error I get hen I try to use DaggerAppCompatActivity as a base class for activity mentioned as @ContributesAndroidInjector. It works fine if I simply do AndroidInjection.inject(this) instead of this inheritance.

```
C:\Users\micha\Workspace\StudioProjects\BirthdayGift\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\mpowloka\birthdaygift\common\di\ApplicationComponent.java:8: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment>,javax.inject.Provider<dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment>>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface ApplicationComponent {
                ^
      java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment>,javax.inject.Provider<dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment>>> is injected at
          dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector.<init>(injectorFactories)
      dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector<androidx.fragment.app.Fragment> is injected at
          dagger.android.support.DaggerAppCompatActivity.supportFragmentInjector
      com.mpowloka.birthdaygift.persons.PersonsActivity is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)
  component path: com.mpowloka.birthdaygift.common.di.ApplicationComponent ? com.mpowloka.birthdaygift.common.di.ActivityBindingModule_PersonsActivity.PersonsActivitySubcomponent
```

EDIT 2: my project dependencies (included from separate gradle file):

```
ext.room = dependencyGroup {
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
}

ext.dagger = dependencyGroup {
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$dagger_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger_version"
}

ext.coreTesting = dependencyGroup {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.21.0'
    testImplementation 'org.awaitility:awaitility:3.1.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.21.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.awaitility:awaitility:3.1.2'
}

ext.androidArchitecture = dependencyGroup {
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$lifecycle_version"
}

ext.views = dependencyGroup {
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}


ext {

    kotlin_version = '1.2.71'

    room_version = '2.0.0-beta01'
    dagger_version = "2.16"
    lifecycle_version = '2.0.0-beta01'

}
```

Comment: What's your dependencies look like? have you both android.useAndroidX and android.enableJetifier set to true from your gradle.properties file? Did you try to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: @SamuelEminet I dont know what is anroid.enableJetifier... I did try to rebuild ofc and I will include my gradle dependencies in a second

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @GianMS Somehow we managed to do it in another project, but for some reason now I cannot reproduce it... Fallback I'm currently using in this project is not to use support Fragments (what obviously is not acceptable in long term). As soon as I manage to fix it here I will post an answer.

Answer (score 5):

**I solved this problem.**

this is my dependency:

> implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.16"
>
> implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.16"
>
> kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16"
>
> kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.16"

Answer (score 1):

Some things to try/check:

Is androidx enabled in `gradle.properties`? Like `android.useAndroidX=true`

In `build.gradle` in latest versions this plugin can be applied
`apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`

Remove old imports for support classes (Fragment, AppCompatActivity) and re-import again.

Check that gradle dependencies for androidx are there:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

And then clean and/or File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart